# Add PRIMARY KEY constraint to existing table

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, ddl

I backed up and recovered 2 weeks ago and all primary keys and foreign keys were disabled.
How can I change it?

I'm using Django btw. Unfortunately, I have no idea about DB.

[image]

Comment: Please show your table definition as *text*. Images are discouraged for the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE user_user_user_permissions
ADD CONSTRAINT user_user_user_permissions_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Of course, data in the `id` column must be `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`, or you get an exception trying.

If a different `PRIMARY KEY` constraint exists, drop that first:

```
ALTER TABLE user_user_user_permissions
  DROP CONSTRAINT old_constraint_name
, ADD CONSTRAINT user_user_user_permissions_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

You can look up the name of the existing constraint in pgAdmin under "Constraints" like you show in the picture.

Comment: Thanks! i have a question doesn't the existing data mix? When creating a new model, it causes problems, but there is no problem using it, so I have been using it.

Comment: @chea: Not sure about Django behavior. I just answered the question how to add a PK in Postgres.

Comment: Then can't we just overwrite the settings of the existing data? I have previously backed up data which has correct setting (primary key is enabled )

Comment: @chea: Data has no settings. a PK constraint is a detail of the database schema (or design). Your `backed up data` is ignorant of any existing PK constraint (unless you included the schema in the backup). Of course, if the source DB had a PK on that column, values are `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` implicitly.

Comment: Thank you so much. So can we restore  previous schema to the current data?

Comment: @chea: Maybe you can set up a new table (in a new schema / database) and then load the data into that new table. That would be simplest. You may be able to "restore previous schema to the current data", too, but that's a more tricky operation.